# Tmux change scroll up/down keys

Tags: vim, vi, tmux

Currently when I want to go into scroll mode I press `Ctrl+b` and then `[`. However after entering copy-mode, I must use the up and down keys to scroll up or down. I would prefer to `k` for up and `j` for down.

How do I change the scrolling behaviour so that scroll down happens when I press `k` and scroll up happens when I press `j`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use a `.tmux.conf` file with something similar to the following, which I adapted to your question

```
# Set tmux to Vi mode
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
# Scroll up/down with j/k
bind-key -t vi-copy 'j' page-down
bind-key -t vi-copy 'k' page-up
```

Although this seems unnecessary because in vi mode, the `hjkl` work as expected, and you scroll up/down with `J/K` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) which work just fine

To make it even more Vim-like I add following:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection                  
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

Which works like Vim's visual select and yank

<sub>**Note**: After configuring the file you have to reload it, e.g. with the tmux command `:source ~/.tmux.conf`</sub>

Comment: only need to swap j and k .

Comment: @Anzumana Thanks, fixed, J key is now down and K is up like vi.

Answer (score 1):

For those with later versions of Tmux:

```
# set tmux to Vi mode
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
# scroll up/down with j/k
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi j send-keys -X page-up
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi k send-keys -X page-down
# v for selection y for yanking
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
```